# Get all the occurances of sub string of particular length after specified string

Tags: java

For e.g. get sub string of 3 characters after "abc".

```
abcxyzabcpqrabclmnoabcdef
```

output should be

```
xyz
prq
lmn
def
```

I am able to fetch only first occurrence but not all.

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Look for **Pattern, Matcher, find**. And regex "abc(...)". Or `String.indexOf("abc", startindex)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex to do this:

```
(?<=abc)...
```

`(?<=abc)` means to only match the pattern after it if the characters `abc` is present before it. And the `...` means to match 3 of any character.

```
final String regex = "(?<=abc)...";
final String string = "abcxyzabcpqrabclmnoabcdef";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: you can also use this regex `(?<=abc).{3}`

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code snipped, it would work for you.

```
    String str="abcxyzabcpqrabclmnoabcdef";
    String[] strCsv=str.split("abc");
    for(int i=0;i<strCsv.length;i++){
        String str1=strCsv[i];
        if(str1.length()>=3)
        {
            System.out.println(str1.substring(0,3));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer to warrant the downvote?